# Вывод дерева категорий. Что не так?

Tags: php, twig, redbeanphp

**Нужен такой вывод:**

```
Главная категория
-Подкатегория
--Суб категория
-Подкатегория 2
--Суб категория  
Главная 2  
Главная 3  
Главная 4
-Просто категория
---А в ней ещё одна
```

**Выводит только:**

```
Главная категория
Главная 2  
Главная 3  
Главная 4
```

```
static function getTreeCategories()
    {

        $categories = R::findAll('categories'); # Получаем список всех категорий

        foreach ($categories as $category) {

            $main = R::findAll('categories', 'parent_id = 0'); # Получаем список корневых категорий

            foreach ($main as $m) {

                $parent = R::findAll('categories', 'parent_id = ?', array($m->id)); # Получаем список категорий с parent_id равному корневой категории

                foreach ($parent as $p) {
                    $sub_parent = R::findAll('categories', 'parent_id = ?', array($p->id)); # Получаем список категорий с parent_id равному подкатегории
                }

            }

        }


        return array(
            'main' => $main ?? NULL, 
            'parent' => $parent ?? NULL, 
            'sub_parent' => $sub_parent ?? NULL
        );
    }
```

Клиентская часть:

```
<select name="category" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                <option value="">Не выбрано</option>
                {% for main in categories.main %}
                    <option disabled="">{{ main.name }}</option>

                    {% for parent in categories.parent %}
                        <option disabled="">{{ main.name }}:{{ parent.name }}</option>

                        {% for sub_parent in categories.sub_parent %}
                            <option value="{{ main.slug }}:{{ parent.slug }}:{{ sub_parent.slug }}">{{ main.name }}:{{ parent.name }}:{{ sub_parent.name }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}

                    {% endfor %}

                {% endfor %}
              </select>
```

Comment: Самое время именно Вам написать что не так.

Comment: Выводит только категории с parent_id = 0 и всё

Comment: Теперь напишите, как должно быть...

Comment: Написал в вопросе